# Show that $f_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ does not converge uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

So I know of three possible ways to try and prove something is not uniformly convergent and I have tried all three but not one of them has given me peace about a definitive answer.

I know for $[0,1)$ this function converges uniformly to $f(x)=1$

Now for the interval $[0,1]$ the limit function $f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      1 & 0\le x< 1 \\
      \frac{1}{2} & x=1
    \end{cases}
$

I thought I could use this definition I have, to prove it is not UC but I am not sure if it works right.Let me know what you think:

The definition states:

The function sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ fails to converge uniformly on $D$ to the function $f(x)$ provided that there exists a positive number $\epsilon$ that for infinitley many $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a number $x_n$ in $D$ satisfying $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| \ge \epsilon.$

So say I choose $\epsilon =\frac{1}{6}$ and I let $x_n =(\frac{1}{2})^{1/n}$

Obviously $x_n$ is in $D$ and   $x_n\le 1$for infinitley many $n\in \mathbb{N}$

So now we evaluate our inequality and notice

$|\frac{1}{1+((\frac{1}{2})^{1/n})^n}-1|=| \frac{2}{3}|\ge\frac{1}{6}$ and
$|\frac{1}{1+((\frac{1}{2})^{1/n})^n}-\frac{1}{2}|=| \frac{1}{6}|\ge\frac{1}{6}$

Thus we can conclude that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on $f(x)$

Does this proof look correct? if not can you suggest some other method or point me in the right direction?

Comment: You just need to show that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| \ge \epsilon $ for **one** $x_n$. The proof looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f_n({1 \over \sqrt[n]{3}}) = {3 \over 4}$ for all $n$.

Hence $|f_n({1 \over \sqrt[n]{3}}) -f({1 \over \sqrt[n]{3}})| = {1 \over 4}$
for all $n$.

Comment: that is essentially what i have done just a different fraction...so is this a valid proof that confirms this function sequence is not uniformly convergent on the given domain?

Comment: @Bry: Your proof looks fine, you only need to show one $x_n$ for which the difference is $\ge \epsilon$.

Comment: is that not what I did?

Comment: Well, you only need show that $|f(x_n) -1| \ge {1 \over 6}$. The other is irrelevant.

Comment: i don't have to consider the case when the number $x_n=1$  and then f(1)=1/2? Considering that the limit function takes on two values on the domain

Comment: Like I said, you only need to show that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \ge \epsilon$ for **one** $x$. Your additional inequality above is irrelevant as it is showing that $|f_n(x_n) - f(1)| \ge {1 \over 6}$. You are evaluating $f_n,f$ at different points, which you are perfectly entitled to do, but it has no bearing on the proof.